# Getting a copy of elements inside a ScrollView from one view controller to another swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to get all the elements (UItextfields) that I have in defined in  `myScrollView` in class `AddViewController` to another `FormViewController` where I have just an empty `getFormView` scrollview where I want to get all the elements of `myScrollView` to be appear, whether in a form of copy or getting that same.

I am adding subview of `myScrollView` to `getFormView` but this gives me error 
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional

I am creating textfields by getting an input, like if set input to 7 the seven textfields will be generated in form and by clicking on creating I want these testfields should be in formViewController's uiscrollview that is getformview

**FormViewController**

```
import UIKit

class FormViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var getFormView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menu.target = revealViewController()
    menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


    getFormView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    getFormView.scrollsToTop = true
    getFormView.isScrollEnabled = true
    getFormView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 343, height: 1500)

    print("formViewController")

    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
    let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController


    self.view.addSubview(self.getFormView)
    self.getFormView.addSubview(desController.myScrollView)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

**AddViewController Image of my myScrollView**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7izIW.png)

**FormViewController image of getFormView**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFqSn.png)

**AddViewController**

```
import UIKit

class AddViewController: UIViewController {

var templateName : String?
var templateDesc : String?

var noButtons : Int?
var noTextFields : Int?
var noLabels : Int?


var xValue = 20, yValue = 100
var tagNo = 0
var textObjects : Array<Any>?
var incrementerText : Int?

var xButton = 15 , yButton = 90
var tagButton = 10
var buttonObject : Array<Any>?
var buttonIncreament : Int?

var xLabel = 10 , yLabel = 80
var tagLabel = 15
var labelObject : Array<Any>?
var labelIncreament : Int?


@IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!


@IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
@IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {

    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
    let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
    let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)

}


@IBOutlet weak var createForms: UIButton!
@IBAction func createForms(_ sender: Any) {



    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
    let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FormViewController") as! FormViewController

   // desController.getFormView.addSubview(myScrollView)


    let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
    revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)



}





@IBAction func addForm(_ sender: Any) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Create Template", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    alertController.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
      //  textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.keyboardType = .default
        textField.autocorrectionType = .default
        textField.placeholder = "Title"
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

    }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        //textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.keyboardType = .default
        textField.autocorrectionType = .default
        textField.placeholder = "Description"
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    }


    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
       UIAlertAction in
    print("Ok action")

            let templateText = alertController.textFields![0]
            let descriptionText = alertController.textFields![1]
        self.templateName = templateText.text!
        self.templateDesc = descriptionText.text!

        if self.templateName?.isEmpty == false && self.templateDesc?.isEmpty == false {

        print("Template: \(templateText.text!)\nDescription: \(descriptionText.text!)")
        print("\(String(describing: self.templateName!)), \(String(describing: self.templateDesc!))")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.drawPop()
    }
    else {
        self.okAlert()
    }


    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
    }


    //alertController.addAction(alertActionOkay)
    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
 //   alertController.willChangeValue(forKey: "Continue")
    // Present the controller
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func drawPop() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\(self.templateName!)", message: "\(self.templateDesc!)", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //attributing textfields labels



    alertController.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        //textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
       // textField.keyboardType = .default
        textField.placeholder = "TextFileds"
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

    }

   alertController.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
       // textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        textField.autocorrectionType = .default
        textField.placeholder = "Buttons"
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        // textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        textField.autocorrectionType = .default
        textField.placeholder = "Labels"
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    }


    // Create the actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("OK Pressed")

        let notextFieldText = alertController.textFields![0]
        let noButtonText = alertController.textFields![1]
        let noLabelText = alertController.textFields![2]


        self.noTextFields = Int(notextFieldText.text!)
        self.noButtons = Int(noButtonText.text!)
        self.noLabels = Int(noButtonText.text!)

        print("Template: \(notextFieldText.text!)\nDescription: \(noButtonText.text!)")
        print("\(noLabelText.text!)")

        print("\(String(describing: self.noTextFields!)), \(String(describing: self.noButtons!)) , \(String(describing: self.noLabels!))")




        self.createForms.isHidden = false
        self.myScrollView.isHidden = false
        self.reset.isHidden = false



        self.incrementerText = 20
        if self.noTextFields! > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<self.noTextFields! {
                print ("hello")

                let sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: self.xValue, y: self.yValue, width: 300, height: 40))
                sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
                sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
                sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
                sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
                sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
                sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
                sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
                sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
                sampleTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
                sampleTextField.tag = self.tagNo
               // self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)


                //trying to print at container view
               self.view.addSubview(self.myScrollView)
               self.myScrollView.addSubview(sampleTextField)



               let frametext = sampleTextField.frame.size.height

                self.textObjects?.append(sampleTextField)

                self.yValue = self.yValue + Int(frametext) + 20
                self.xValue = 20
            }
        }

        else {
            print("no text field found")
        }




        self.buttonIncreament = 20
        if self.noButtons! > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<self.noButtons! {
                print ("Buttons")

                let sampleButton =  UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.xButton, y: self.yButton, width: 150, height: 25))

                sampleButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
                sampleButton.tag = self.tagNo
               // self.view.addSubview(sampleButton)
                let frametext = sampleButton.frame.size.height

                self.view.addSubview(self.myScrollView)
                self.myScrollView.addSubview(sampleButton)


                self.buttonObject?.append(sampleButton)

                self.yButton = self.yButton + Int(frametext) + 20
                self.xButton = 20

            }
        }

        else {
            print("no button found")
        }





        self.labelIncreament = 20
        if self.noLabels! > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<self.noLabels! {
                print ("Labels")

                let sampleLabel =  UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.xLabel, y: self.yLabel, width: 150, height: 25))

               // sampleLabel.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
                sampleLabel.tag = self.tagNo
                // self.view.addSubview(sampleButton)
                let frameLabel = sampleLabel.frame.size.height

                self.view.addSubview(self.myScrollView)
                self.myScrollView.addSubview(sampleLabel)


                self.labelObject?.append(sampleLabel)

                self.yLabel = self.yLabel + Int(frameLabel) + 20
                self.xLabel = 20

            }
        }

        else {
            print("no button found")
        }















        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
    }

    //alertController.addAction(alertActionOkay)
    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    // Present the controller
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func createForm() {

    let sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
    sampleTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)


}

func okAlert() {

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Enter required data", preferredStyle: .alert)

let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

/*

let scrollmyView : UIScrollView  = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()

    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = true
    // myScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1500)


    return scrollView

}()
*/

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menu.target = revealViewController()
    menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())




      myScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
      myScrollView.scrollsToTop = true
     // myScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
      myScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
      myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 343, height: 1500)
   // scroller.contentSize = CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)


    createForms.isHidden = true
    myScrollView.isHidden = true
    reset.isHidden = true


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

**Error**

[Full screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WZAV.png)

Comment: Make an `IBOutlet` of all `UITextField` and pass `YourTextField.text` to next view controller when you click on create button.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni thanx for your comment sir, but I am creating textfields by getting an input, like if set input to 7 the seven textfields will be generated in form and by clicking on creating I want these testfields should be in formViewController's uiscrollview that is getformview

Comment: Ok then you can get subviews of scrollview and then you can get values from textfields.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I am adding subview of `myScrollView` to `getFormView` but this gives me error unexpectedly found nil while uwrapping an optional

Comment: @DharmeshKheni updated question

Comment: can you share demo project?

Comment: yes...........................

Comment: updating...................

Comment: @DharmeshKheni provide me email........

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I have added complete code for addviewcontroller and formviewcontroller for demo project share your email/contact/skype so I can send you

Comment: @DharmeshKheni sent sir,

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using scrollview if you have same type of elements. Best way is to use table view. We use scrollview if the elements in most of the rows are different. Once you use table view you don't have to copy anything.

**Best approach for your problem:**

If you have same type of view controller then you can use one view controller as **AddViewController** and **FormViewController**.

Comment: I will add more elements like buttons lebels and so on but i am just making a demo as if works

Comment: @XcodianSolangi Can you please tell me if both the view controller are look same or different.

Comment: i have added the images for both in question

Comment: Sorry mate it is not possible in iOS.

Comment: If you want to do that then you can do it using table view.

Comment: thanx i will try table views

Answer (score 0):

Create the same UITextFields in your FormViewController.

and when a user fills the form in AddViewController , update the textfields of your FormViewController with the text of AddViewController's text field

Answer (score 0):

```
content.view.frame = CGRect(x: -UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
getFormView = content.scrollView
view.addSubview(content.scollView)
content.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Here content is the view controller that you want to add in you case it is instance of AddViewController

Comment: Its something complicated would you use the names as are in my questions?

Comment: Yes, its not complicated . It is same as what you did. Only difference is who have to add last line.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you are doing this . Coping scrollview from other ViewController to destination view.

Comment: where should I define it in AddVC or FormVC

Comment: In formVC, But this will  just add full view of AddVC to view of formVC. You cannot copy a particular elements.